# Find the number of true's in a TrueQ expression

Tags: code-request, number-representation, expression-form, code

How can I find how many times the code:

```
Table[TrueQ[FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] == 0], {n, 1, m, 1}]
```

Gives the value True back for a variable $m$?

---

So, we know that for example:

- `Table[TrueQ[FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] == 0], {n, 1, 10, 1}]` must give $3$
- `Table[TrueQ[FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] == 0], {n, 1, 50, 1}]` must give $7$
- `Table[TrueQ[FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] == 0], {n, 1, 100, 1}]` must give $10$

Comment: `Count[Table[TrueQ[FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] == 0], {n, #}], 
   True] & /@ {10, 50, 100}` evaluates to `{3, 7, 10}`

Comment: Why are you using `TrueQ` here? It seems like a misuse that might get you in trouble if you do not fully understand what `TrueQ` does. Try e.g. `TrueQ[x==0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Total@Boole@Table[TrueQ[FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] == 0], {n, 1, 100, 1}]
(* 10 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If expr is one of your Tables above:

```
Select[expr, # == True &] // Length
```

returns how many Trues there are.

Answer (score 0):

For any integer `n` you can get the desired number using simply

```
⌊Sqrt@n⌋
```